# How to add a row in a CSV file in pentaho data integration

Tags: csv, pentaho-data-integration

I need to add a row data in a CSV file using Pentaho Data Integration.

I've tried with this transformation

[image]

This is my CSV file input configuration

[image]

and this is the CSV file output configuration (with the "append" check activated ...)

[image]
My constant definition

[image]

and this is my CSV file sample

[image]

I'd like to have this

[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Data grid` step to create your constant data and the `Append streams` step to merge two streams into one in your desired order (data type in two streams must be matched and the same order) and then you can write the data to a CSV file. If you don't need a header present in the CSV file you can uncheck the "Header" option in the content tab

[image: transformation]